# FreeRADIUS clients to access service with username and password with access periods

Tags: freeradius

I am using freeradius/mysql/daloradius.

I need my customers to be able to login using a username and password that they signed up with and at the same time give them different access periods.

How do I accomplish that?

I've attempted editing `/etc/freeradius/sql/mysql/dialup.conf`:

```
authorize_check_query = "SELECT id, username, password, attribute, value, op \
  FROM ${authcheck_table} \
  WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'\
  ORDER BY id"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the logintime module, and call it after the SQL module in `raddb/sites-available/default authorize{}`.

You can then add a row to the radcheck table for the user who's period of access you want to limit, with attribute `Login-Time` op `:=` and value in the format described here [man systems](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51_HTML/MAN/MAN4/0079____.HTM) under the *Time* heading.

The logintime module will reject the user if they are not logging in within an allowed period, and Accept the user, adding the Session-Timeout attribute to force re-authentication when their current allowed access period ends.

Comment: thank alot i even did more research and ended up using Expiration attribute for now it is working just fine

Comment: Ah sure, that should be fine too. It's just this way lets you specify more complex policies with time blocks.